# How to make armor blocks properly merge?

Tags: space-engineers

Screenshot shows a portion of light armor blocks in a plane, part of a fairly large small grid build I'm doing. (This is for the mid-deck floor.)

After welding out the outline of the hull and each deck, I am now filling in the decks in, but for some reason this part of the floor has boundaries, like it's not considering it to be part of the rest. I know that as you weld armor blocks, they'll merge together to save on the number of polygons the engine has to manage. This is a large build, so I really want the armor blocks to merge as much as possible. Why does this happen, and how can I fix it once it is happening?

[image: Image of light armor blocks failing to properly merge into a single shape]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those separating bars usually appear between adjacent armor blocks when are not the exact same color and/or material. Is it possible that those blocks have a slightly different shade of grey than the others?

To repaint blocks already placed in a different color:

1. select any block from your toolbar so your UI is in "place block mode"
2. Select a color, either by using the color picker UI (<kbd>P</kbd>) or by aiming at an existing block and picking its color with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
3. Aim at the block you want to paint
4. Press middle mouse-button. You can also press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Middle Mouse Button</kbd> to paint a 4x4 area or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Middle Mouse Button</kbd> to paint the whole grid in a uniform color.